# Dynamically adding the ReferrerPolicy to an IFrame

Tags: typescript

How can I add this referrerPolicy attribute to the iframe via typescript?

This is a sample code, that does not work.

```
protected createIframeElement(): void {
    this.iframeElement = document.createElement('iframe');
    this.iframeElement.title = this.getIframeTitle();
    this.iframeElement.style.height = '620px';
    this.iframeElement.src = this.someUrl;
    **this.iframeElement.referrerPolicy = 'unsafe-url';**
    this.iframeContainer.appendChild(this.iframeElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works.
this.iframeElement.setAttribute('referrerpolicy', 'unsafe-url');